# Count substrings in an array of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, count, substring

I would like to count the number of use of Mr and Miss in the array.

I'v started with one of them and been trying a couple of solutions.

But I can't get my head around how to sum the counts of the whole array, like when I console.log it, it will print each one of them, not the sum of all Mr in the array?

````
const array = [
  "Hello Mr, Hello Miss",
  "Hello Mr, Hello Miss",
  "Hello Mr, Hello Miss",
  "Hello Mr, Hello Miss"
];
console.log(array);

array.forEach((object) => {
  var count = (object.match(/Miss/g) || []).length;
  console.log("Number:", count);
});
```
````

Comment: You could simply join the strings before counting: `(array.join(' ').match(/Miss|Mr/g) || []).length`

Comment: Thanks @secan thats a great solution, never thought about that.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const array = [
  "Hello Mr, Hello Miss",
  "Hello Mr, Hello Miss",
  "Hello Mr, Hello Miss",
  "Hello Mr, Hello Miss"
];
console.log(array);

const count = (array.join(' ').match(/Miss|Mr/g) || []).length;
console.log(count);
```